# f.association with current_user in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am building a website where a user can create a "project" which contains several "papers".

I am trying to link the creation of a new "project" with the specific user who is creating it. To do so, I am passing as `hidden value` the `current_user` in a `simple_form`. However, I am not able to do so, in fact the project does not save.
**However,** if I modify the following line:

```
<%= f.association :user, label: "Which user is creating it?",
:as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => current_user }  %>
```

with

```
        <%= f.association :user%>
```

It allows me to choose among all the users and, if I select one, it does create the "project".

**Therefore**, I think my problem is the way I am passing the `current_user` in the `simple_form`. I am passing it this way `:input_html => { :value => current_user }`

**_form_new.html.erb**

```
  <%= current_user%> #IT DISPLAYS CORRETLY THE CURRENT USER

<div class="container">

  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0">

<%= simple_form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

      <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :title, label: "Write the title of the project you are creating" %>
        <%= f.input :body, label: "Write a short summary of the project you are adding", as: :text, input_html: {rows: 15, cols: 10} %>
        <%= f.association :user, :as => :hidden, label: "Which user is creating it?", :input_html => { :value => current_user }  %>

      </div>

      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :projects
end
```

**Project.rb**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :papers
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass `current_user.id` through the form, even in a hidden field, any user can change it and create a project for someone else. Not sure if you want it. Correct approach is to call `current_user.projects.build` in a controller.

```
def create
  @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
  if @project.save
    redirect_to projects_path
  else
    render :new
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I had to pass and `id` to `current user`.

Correct way:

```
<%= f.input :title, label: "Write the title of the project you are creating" %>
<%= f.input :body, label: "Write a short summary of the project you are adding", as: :text, input_html: {rows: 15, cols: 10} %>
<%= f.association :user, label: "Which user is creating it?",
:as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => current_user.id }  %>
```